# Can I host a websites MySQL Database on my laptop

Tags: php, mysql, host

I have finally finished bootstrap website (thanks to some help from the kind folk in this community) and was wondering if I can host the websites MySQL DB on my personal laptop while the site is hosted through a hosting service?

I have configured a PHP script to send the form data by email but I also want to send it to a MySQL DB which I can administer from my home rather than through the host provider.

Comment: Yes, you can. But note that your laptop will have to be turned on and online 24/7 in order to save everything. If your laptop is offline, your website will likely start throwing database errors and might stop to function at all (depending on how you programmed it). You might just want to set up remote database administration to your hosting provider, so you can manage the database from home by using something like [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) instead.

Comment: It's possible, but What will happen to the site when you shut down your laptop? Or it goes into hibernation?

Comment: this would be great if you could garentee your laptop is connected to the internet 24/7. But most hosting companies include db hosting as standard anyway, so why rish having your website go down in the first place?

Comment: Not recommended, and I don't see any reason to do so. You can host a MySql database on your hosting, and access it using your hosting control panel at any time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can host MySQL DB on your own personal laptop. You can check out XAMPP, for example, which comes as out-of-the-box bundle including not only MySQL but other features as well - PHP, phpmyadmin and so forth: https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html

Comment: thank you but what is the connect string through PHP? I mean, you need to determine the host name where the DB is located right?

Comment: @GregJordan: you should be able to use your ip address if configured correctly.

Comment: You are missing out one thing - He doesn't want to host it as a local database, but as a production database that will receive data from a site hosted on an hosting service. That will require him to setup MySql for public access, and requires a fixed IP address and more. Not that simple, and not from a laptop that will be connected from different WIFI's.

Comment: If public access is needed, then yes, static IP will be required as well and the connection string will be pointing to that static IP (it will only work if the laptop is turned on and connected to the proper network). If you access the DB directly from the laptop, it will be just 'localhost'.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I am taking it that hosting a production MySQL db is probably not the best way to do what I need to do. Hmmm.. essentially I am trying to come up with an effective yet simple way to retrieve the data from the db for people who are not all that tech savvy.